# Doing a Math.Round(x,2) on a decimal value, but need to ensure 2 numbers after decimal as its money

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal, currency

Some values are returning 2.0 but I need it to be 2.00 as this is a money value that is displayed to the web page.

I am doing:

```
Math.Round(value, 2);
```

Is there a way to force it to 2 numbers after the decimal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using a decimal to store monetary values.

But regardless of whether you are using a decimal or floating point type, your question asks how the number can be *displayed* with two decimal places. Use `money.ToString("0.00")` to display two decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

If your using VB.Net use

```
FormatNumber(number, digitsAfter)
```

or

```
FormatCurrency(number, digitsAfter)
```

or this can be in both (C# and Vb.Net)

```
doubleNumber = -1898300.1987;
Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
// Displays -1898300.20
```

See this link for the full ToString() formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Either .ToString("0.00") as Mark suggested if you only need to display .00
or Math.Round(value * 100.0) / 100.0; if you need an actual value with cent accuracy.