# Math.Floor to x digits after decimal

Tags: c#, math

I need to display two digits after decimal point while rounding to floor as a percentage. I wrote out this code to do so, but this looks too complex, is there another more effecient way of doing this?

```
 double decimalPlacesFactor =Math.Pow(10, numberOfDigits+2);
 percentage = Math.Floor((NumA/NumB)*decimalPlacesFactor)/decimalPlacesFactor *100;
```

The output should look like

```
99.78 %
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375735/doing-a-math-roundx-2-on-a-decimal-value-but-need-to-ensure-2-numbers-after-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ToString() methode to convert your number to a string. Display it as a floating point with X digits by using the argument "FX". e.g. "F2" for two digits

```
string percentage = Math.Floor(NumA/NumB).ToString("F"+numberOfDigits);
```

Comment: Can you explain how your Solution works? It would be nice for other visitors. BTW, the inner `ToString` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to display the percentage value, but I am guessing you'll want to show `string` of the percentage? What about:

```
string percentage = Math.Floor(NumA/NumB).ToString("0.00");
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(2.3).ToString("0.00")); //this will output 2.00
```

If you want to make the number of digits after decimal configurable you could create the masking string beforehand, with something like this:

```
private string CreateMaskingString(int numberOfDigits)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("0.");
    sb.Append(new string('0', numberOfDigits));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And usage would look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(2.3).ToString(CreateMaskingString(2))); //this will output 2.00
```

A much more simple and elegant solution looks like this, as has been pointed out by RomCoo:

```
string percentage = Math.Floor(NumA/NumB).ToString("F" + numberOfDigits);
```

What does the "F" mean here? You can read the [explanation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#FFormatString). But basically:

> The fixed-point ("F") format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   the form "-ddd.ddd…" where each "d" indicates a digit (0-9). The
>   string starts with a minus sign if the number is negative.

Comment: that's a good solution, but I want to keep this configurable by specifying the number of digits in  "numberOfDigits"

Comment: @Peroxy you can use `new string('0', numberOfDigits)` instead of your `for`-loop. I think this is more readable.

Comment: @Koopakiller ah yes, much better, I agree.